# How to get a tool by itemId from a CartesianChart object in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a `Ext.chart.CartesianChart` with tools. I'd like to select a tool by itemId, using the chart object `chart_o`. `getComponent` seems to not work.

For now I'm cycling on `chart_o.tools` and check if the itemId matches. Is there a built-in method? I'm using ExtJS 5.1.0

Code:

```
{
    xtype: "Ext.chart.CartesianChart",
    id: "tensioni_modulo",
    title: '<div style="line-height:28px">Tensioni (modulo)</div>',
    tools: [
        {
            type: "maximize",
            itemId: "max",
        },
        {
            type: "minimize",
            itemId: "min",
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug as `tools` is an [`Ext.panel.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tools) configuration, which is effectively a shortcut for specifying child items of the `header` component - which in turn is just a child of your chart panel, and thus should be accessible in the component-query hierarchy.

Having tested this in version 6, it appears to have been fixed - so your best bet is to upgrade your application.  However if that's not possible you can still reference the docked header component by calling the getter imperatively / manually.  ***i.e.***

```js
myChart.getHeader().down('#max'); // works in 5.1
```

Comment: Thank you for details about actual tool components hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

I updated my function using [Emissary's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853996/1763602):

```
function getToolByItemId(parent_id, tool_itemId) {
    /**
     *  @author Marco Sulla (marcosullaroma@gmail.com)
     *  @author Emissary (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853996/1763602)
     *  @date Nov 20, 2015
     */
    
    var p = Ext.getCmp(parent_id);
    
    if (! p) {
        throw new Error("No component with id '" + 
                        parent_id.toString() + "'");
    }
    
    var h = p.getHeader();
    
    if (! h) {
        throw new Error("Component '" + parent_id.toString() + 
                        "' has no header");
    }
    
    var tool = h.down("#" + tool_itemId);
    
    if (! tool) {
        throw new Error("No tool with itemId '" + 
                        tool_itemId.toString() + 
                        "' in component '" + 
                        parent_id.toString() + "'");
    }
    
    return tool;
}
```